# Create dynamically lists for every column of an input file

Tags: java, list, file

I need to create a tool that will create some graphic representation of data.
I need to look into the input file, which can be any .txt or .csv with different number of columns and after that, the user can choose what data want to represent on chart.

Let's say I have an input file like this:

```
Column1;Row1;50;20;Column5 
Column1;Row2;60;30;Column5
Column1;Row3;70;40;Column5
Column1;Row4;80;50;Column5
Column1;Row5;90;60;Column5
```

I need something to create a list for every column the input file has. For this example, to create 5 lists. If it has 10 columns to create 10 lists.
I tried something with a list of lists but I don't know how can I create objects dynamically:

```
try {
            fis = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/User/Desktop/test1.txt");
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));


            String line = reader.readLine();
            String[] column = line.split(";");
            while(line != null){
                singleList.add(column[0]);
                line = reader.readLine();
            } 
            listOfLists.add(singleList);
```

Can anybody help me? If you can with a specific example(I'm kinda new in Java).

Answer (score 2):

Please, don't use custom implementations

[opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)

[Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/)

An example using opencsv

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import com.opencsv.CSVReader;

/**
 *
 * @author V.Ladynev
 */
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Build reader instance
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(
                new FileReader("C:/Users/User/Desktop/test1.txt"), ';', '"');
        // Read all rows at once
        List<String[]> allRows = readAll(reader);

        int colsCount = size(first(allRows));
        if (colsCount == 0) {
            return;
        }

        List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

        for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < colsCount; colIndex++) {
            List<String> col = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (String[] row : allRows) {
                col.add(get(row, colIndex));
            }
            result.add(col);
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result.toArray()));
    }

    public static List<String[]> readAll(CSVReader reader) throws IOException {
        try {
            return reader.readAll();
        } finally {
            reader.close();
        }
    }

    public static <T> T first(List<T> items) {
        return items == null || items.size() == 0 ? null : items.get(0);
    }

    public static <T> int size(T[] array) {
        return array == null ? 0 : array.length;
    }

    public static <T> T get(T[] array, int index) {
        return size(array) > index ? array[index] : null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you want:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/User/Desktop/test1.txt");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

List<List<String>> listOfList = new ArrayList<>();

String line = reader.readLine();
String[] column = line.split(";");

//initial
for(int i = 0; i<column.length;i++){
    listOfList.add(new ArrayList<String>());
}

while(line != null){
    column = line.split(";");
    for(int i = 0; i<column.length;i++){
        istOfList.get(i).add(column[i]);
    }

    line = reader.readLine();
}

System.out.println(listOfList);
```

Comment: You need to split every line not the first

Comment: Please, add my name to your comment next time  for upvoting :)